# Reactivating previous workbook in for loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a macro that opens one workbook, copies data for 24 hours into an array using VLOOKUP then pastes the array into main workbook and then it should be going back to the opened workbook and copy another set of data into the array. Unfortunately after copying first set of data I get "Subscript out of range". I know that the reason is that macro tries to activate a workbook that it can't find even though it's already opened

```
Sub main()

Dim fname As String, pathfile As String, year As Long, month As Long, day As Long
Dim version As Long, nazwa_raportu As String, miesiac As String, dzien As String
Dim hour As Long, godzina As Long
Dim Arr(1 To 10) As String, Data(0 To 23) As Long
Dim i As Long, fullname As String

Arr(1) = "somename1"
Arr(2) = "somename2"
Arr(3) = "somename3"
Arr(4) = "somename4"
Arr(5) = "somename5"
Arr(6) = "somename6"
Arr(7) = "somename7"
Arr(8) = "somename8"
Arr(9) = "somename9"
Arr(10) = "somename10"

For month = 1 To 12
    If month < 10 Then
        miesiac = "0" & month
    Else
        miesiac = month
    End If

    For day = 1 To 31
        If day < 10 Then
            dzien = "0" & day
        Else
            dzien = day
        End If

        Do
            pathfile = "C:\Users\M\Documents\Reports\XXXX\ARDR\"
            fname = pathfile & miesiac & "_" & dzien & "_" & ".xls"
            ' if file not present skip
            If Len(Dir(fname)) = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Workbooks.Open (fname)
            fullname = Application.ActiveWorkbook.fullname

            For i = 1 To 10
                For hour = 0 To 23
                    Data(hour) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Arr(i), Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 80)), 4 + 3 * hour, False)
                Next hour
                For godzina = 0 To 23
                    Workbooks("main.xlsm").Activate
                    Cells(3 + godzina * day, 1 + i * 2) = Dane(godzina)
                Next godzina
                Workbooks(fullname).Activate
            Next i

        Loop While False
    Next day
Next month
```

How can I reactivate workbook that I have opened before loop

```
 For i = 1 To 10
```

While I'm still in that loop?

Comment: You can do `Set srcWB = Workbooks(source workbook name)` and `Set trgWB = Workbooks(target workbook name)` so that way you can switch back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below (i've commented the new lines I've added) :

```
Dim NewWB As Workbook ' <-- New Workbook Object declaration

For month = 1 To 12
    If month < 10 Then
        miesiac = "0" & month
    Else
        miesiac = month
    End If

    For day = 1 To 31
        If day < 10 Then
            dzien = "0" & day
        Else
            dzien = day
        End If

        Do
            pathfile = "C:\Users\M\Documents\Reports\XXXX\ARDR\"
            fname = pathfile & miesiac & "_" & dzien & "_" & ".xls"
            ' if file not present skip
            If Len(Dir(fname)) = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(fname) '<-- Set the Opened workbook to a Workbook Object

            For i = 1 To 10
                For hour = 0 To 23
                    Data(hour) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Arr(i), Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 80)), 4 + 3 * hour, False)
                Next hour
                For godzina = 0 To 23
                    Workbooks("main.xlsm").Activate
                    Cells(3 + godzina * day, 1 + i * 2) = Dane(godzina)
                Next godzina
                NewWB.Activate ' <-- activate again (inside the loop)
            Next i

        Loop While False

        Set NewWB = Nothing '<-- Clear Object
    Next day
Next month
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I wiil as soon as I get 15 rep. :) I am at 11 right now.